# Export class with renamed methods in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In my code I was using a class astonishingly named `MyClass` which had a single method `MyMethod(): void {...}`  which provided an awesome functionality. Those class+method were used at many places.

There's now a brand new class named `BrandNewClass` (which I can't edit due to *[insert whatever reason would convince you]*) having a single method `BrandNewMethod(): void {...}` providing the same functionality in an improved way.

In order to switch the old functionality with the brand new one, I already got rid of `MyClass` (and `MyMethod`).

After that, I could change references to `MyClass` and `MyMethod` to `BrandNewClass` and  `BrandNewMethod` **everywhere**.

But, I could ease the effort if I re-export `BrandNewClass` as `MyClass` and just change `MyMethod` to `BrandNewMethod`.

```
export { BrandNewClass as MyClass } from 'BrandNewClass';
```

Is there a way to further ease the effort and configure the re-export so the method's name `BrandNewMethod` also gets aliased (to `MyMethod`)?

Answer (score 1):

```
export class MyClass extends BrandNewClass {
    constructor() {
        super(); 
        console.log("MyClass is deprecated, use BrandNewClass")
    }

    public MyMethod() { super.BrandNewMethod(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use another .ts file to control the case, suppose the file is named exports.ts

```
import { MyClass } from "./MyClass";
import { BrandNewClass } from "./BrandNewClass";

export interface IExportClass {
    ClassInstance: any;
    DoThisAwesomeFunction: Function;
}

export function GetExportClass(isNew: boolean): IExportClass {
    var instance;
    if (!isNew) {
        instance = new MyClass();
        return {
            ClassInstance: instance,
            DoThisAwesomeFunction: instance.MyMethod
        }
    }
    else {
        instance = new BrandNewClass();
        return {
            ClassInstance: instance,
            DoThisAwesomeFunction: instance.BrandNewMethod
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
import { GetExportClass, IExportClass } from "./exports";

// global setting 
var usingNewMethod: boolean = true;

var methodDriver: IExportClass = GetExportClass(usingNewMethod);
methodDriver.DoThisAwesomeFunction();
```